# Jackson Ignore Null and Empty Values for Map

Tags: java, json, jackson

I apologise as I know this question has been asked numerous times and I have read nearly all the threads on this that I can find but I really am beginning to lose my mind.  I currently have an object which contains a map

```
Map <String, String>
```

The map is basically name value pairs which I want to convert into JSON using Jackson.  The thing is, the value of the name may be null or empty, ie an empty string for example and i dont want these to show up in the JSON at all.  I've tried the NON_NULL and NON_EMPTY annotations on the classes as well as trying to set them globally but nothing seems to be working.  I've even tried copying and pasting the example below from https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-ignore-null-and-empty-fields and even that doesn't seem to be working for me.  Can anyone spot if I am doing something incredibly stupid or is this example also not working for other people?  I'm using Jackson 2.0.4 and unfortunately cannot upgrade.

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("A11", "Mahesh");
        map.put("A22", null);
        map.put("A33", "");
        String jsonMap = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
             .writeValueAsString(map);
        System.out.println("Example is: " + jsonMap);
```

I expected and want the output to be:

```
{
  "A11" : "Mahesh"
}
```

but it was in fact:

```
{
  "A11" : "Mahesh",
  "A33" : "",
  "A22" : null
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For Jackson 2.0.4 it outputs nulls, however for jackson 2.9.8 it outputs your expected output.

Comment: You can write serializer for Map which will remove key with null or empty value

Comment: Frustrating how its working differently in the different version but thank you for your response.  Appreciate it.